# A girl discovers she has fairy blood, becomes a fairy then a mermaid

Tags: story-identification, fairy, mermaids, sequel

It basically has a girl who comes across fairies and figures out she has fairy blood too. When her parents figure it out, they host a little party for the fairies and their girl who's going to be a fairy too. Then the girl becomes a fairy. In the sequel to this book the girl becomes a mermaid. So, she's basically mermaid AND a fairy. I don't remember its name. I read it a few years ago.

Comment: A more descriptive title would be helpful. Maybe something like: "(Children's?) Book series about a girl who discovers she is a Fairy. In the second book she finds out she is a mermaid."

Comment: I love the increasing implausibility. In a sequel, she becomes a werewolf and then, in a real twist, a chartered accountant. (In the US version, then a meth dealer.)

Comment: @releseabe And in the British version, a lion tamer.